# Is interpreted language secured?

Tags: php, security, compilation

For example, I have a php script which contains the source code.
I uploaded it to my web server.
For some reason, some attacker could be able to download that file from my web server. They can be able to read and analyze my source code.

So i think this makes interpreted languages (like php ...) not secured vs a compiled language (which contains only binary form).

I want to hear different opinions about this.

Comment: A language is not by definition secure or insecure just because people can download source files. If you had configured your server not to serve source files as downloadable then this problem is almost insignificant.

Comment: In this case it is not the interpreted language that is not secure, it is your server.

Comment: It's neither an issue if said source follows contemporary safer coding guidelines.

Answer (score 6):

Binary isn't secure either. Granted they need to be a bit more of an elite hacker to disassemble it and get the critical algorithm they're after but if someone has access to the binary your algorithm is as good as leaked.

Comment: I think that was called security by obscurity. But anyway I think that script vs binary security is the least of the problem in the web server security, let's just say that every use of "eval" (or anything without scrubbing your user data ) is deserving your server to be compromised.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget binaries can also be reverse engineered that's why they are not secure either. You have to check for server and network level security.

Answer (score 2):

If you're server is set up to handle PHP files, it will compile and execute them prior to sending the output.  The actual file will not be downloaded.  However, I have seen people name include files with extensions other than *.php, such as *.inc, and they didn't make sure the server would handle those files correctly.  This can be dangerous, as include files often contain configuration data.

So, as mentioned by sberry2A, it's all about the server set up rather than the language itself.   But, it's certainly something that should have attention paid to it.